# Composer will only execute as root, will not execute as common user

Tags: composer-php

Composer has worked fine without incident. I recently upgraded my Mac (Mojave) to PHP 7.2.12 using homebrew.

Now I'm unable to run composer. It simply hangs and does nothing, yet if I run it as sudo it runs fine.

I've already validated:

1. Composer lives in my `/usr/local/bin` folder and that folder is in the $PATH
2. Composer's permissions are 0755
3. I've checked the `~/.composer` folder and it is owned by the user with proper permissions

I've tried removing it and re-installing, yet I experience the same hang as soon as I go to run `php composer-setup.php`

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: What does this `composer-setup.php` file do?

Comment: php composer-setup.php is the install for composer

Comment: Can you run any Composer command with `-vvv` added (e.g. `composer install -vvv`) and update your question with the output?

Comment: There is no output, it just hangs. Incredibly strange though as running it with sudo works fine. I noticed this happened after upgrading to PHP 7.2 but I had thought this was some sort of permission issue. I've checked all permissions and everything appears fine.

Comment: Sorry, no idea then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging my application I realized that when I ran the `composer` manager that it had a debug break in it that was being cause by xdebug in phpStorm.

So future note to anyone who encounters a similar issue, make sure your debugger is disabled when you run composer.